# Is there a way to send activity feed notification in MS teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have designed a bot that interacts with the user using a few commands and is capable of receiving notifications using proactive message as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). Now I was hoping to send a notification in the "activity feed" whenever a notification is received by the user. Can someone point me in the direction of how to do that?

Comment: There are ways. Your post requires more context. You haven't shown what you have tried. I have done this from Jenkins CI using an Office 365 plugin and adding a webhook to the MS Teams channel. No one can guess what you need or looking for unless you add a better explanation and minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: @star - You can add activity feed notifications to your bot messages by adding notification alert. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#adding-notifications-to-your-message) for more info?

Answer (score 0):

You can add activity feed notifications to your bot messages by adding notification alert. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#adding-notifications-to-your-message) for more info